trouble building electron on mac with 7zip error
running electron builder:
electron-builder --mac

got this error message:
⨯ Exit code: EACCES. spawn /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/node_modules/7zip-bin/mac/x64/7za EACCES  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: Exit code: EACCES. spawn /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/node_modules/7zip-bin/mac/x64/7za EACCES

unsure why it is failing

no up to date Apple Dev account. The build/package process can't sign the code:
• skipped macOS application code signing  reason=cannot find valid "Developer ID Application" identity or custom non-Apple code signing certificate, it could cause some undefined behaviour, e.g. macOS localized description not visible, see https://electron.build/code-signing allIdentities=  1) 673686243ADE52722EED4A548F06B6A5749BEAB4 "localhost" (CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED)


For the custom code signing certificate try using - instead of the name of a certificate.  Also check that the binary which failed to execute has the execute permission set.
